# pack exceeds maximum allowed size -- aws

Tags: java, git, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, git-bash

i am trying to push the code in the repository, but i am getting the next error

> Test@Prueba Ejemplo % git push Enumerating objects: 4, done. Counting
> objects: 100% (4/4), done. remote: fatal: pack exceeds maximum allowed
> size error: RPC failed; curl 55 LibreSSL SSL_write:
> error:02FFF020:system library:func(4095):Broken pipe, errno 32 Writing
> objects: 100% (3/3), 1.28 GiB | 4.57 MiB/s, done. Total 3 (delta 0),
> reused 1 (delta 0), pack-reused 0 error: remote unpack failed:
> unpack-objects abnormal exit Everything up-to-date

The repository is in AWS.

The folder size is  1.8 GB

Comment: The error means what it says: you put too much stuff in. There's a limit, you've exceeded it.

Comment: @torek  How can i fix it ?

Comment: Don't put so much stuff in your repository. (Make a fresh clone, don't put gigabytes of stuff in it.) Your other main option is to find a service that *does* allow multiple gigabytes of stuff - this probably costs more though.

Comment: Are you committing dependencies? How is the repo that big?

Comment: This error usually means that the one specific commit is too large, not the repository as a whole. Try committing in smaller chunks.